# Execute a method in a running jar by php

Tags: java, php

As the title says, is there a way to execute a method of a jar by PHP? Or do i have to run a web host like tomcat in the jar so the PHP script can call this method through REST?

Both (PHP and the running jar) are on the same server.

**Edit:** The jar is already running, so is there a way to execute a method of that jar while running?

Comment: In both directions you have system calls. Without further info it is difficult to tell what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: In PHP, you can use `shell_exec`. So no, you don't have to run an (embedded) webserver in the jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you could use the exec() function of php. But be careful with that, it can be unsafe.

anyway, I think you can do something like

`<?php exec("java -jar bla.jar ..."); ?>`

EDIT: here's the php reference page for it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

EDIT 2:

If the application is already running and is supposed to do something then you might want to use some kind of server client architecture with IPC. Like the running jar provides a socket and you write a client that is executed by php and tells the server app via the socket what it should do. so the command chain would be php --> jclient --> jserver

Comment: sry, edited the question, main point is, that the jar is already running

Comment: well, what exactly do you want to do then? If the application is already running and is supposed to do something then you might want to use some kind of server client architecture with IPC. Like the running jar provides a socket and you write a client that is executed by php and tells the server app via the socket what it should do.



so the command chain would be php -<exec("java -jar jclient.jar \"do something\"")>-> jclient -<socket>-> jserver

Comment: yes that's what i thought of. instead the sockets i would use REST. ok thanks, edit your answer with that suggestions and I accept it.

Comment: alright, glad I could help you.
Anyway, I haven't coded for php in ages and didn't know of REST, but from what I've read you still seem to need some kind of java client that you call through php since it looks like it only connects to php functions.